# How to get the ip address of both side end to end?

Tags: javascript

How to get the both ip address while accessing to browser (www. google.com).
 google side router ip address and my own router ip address .I have already tried to get my ip address from javascript but i am not able to get browser end router ip address. I am stuck with my project.

Comment: you can not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/get-client-ip-using-just-javascript

Comment: if you need IP addresses, perhaps you need to rethink your code altogether

Comment: There's no built-in way to get your public IP. You would have to call an external API, and it can detect your public IP.

Comment: You can write a simple API on your server that does it.

Comment: could anybody help me how to write api code  in my server that is also fine if there is no such codes.

Comment: ok thanks i understand. i would like to close this case.